# Index of child views in custom RelativeLayout

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

I would like to know how the child views in my custom RelativeLayout is drawn so that I can use `getChildAt()` (the childviews are defined in xml).

In particular, my layout contains 5 of these custom layout each containing a number of child views. Most solution I seen seem to be using `findViewById()` and `indexOfChild()`, however, since each child view with the same id would appear 5 times I am unsure if this method can be implemented. As a side note I would also like to know if how the index is determined so that when I make modification to the custom layout I would know how to adjust the index. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`RelativeLayout` does not override `getChildAt`, so the order is the one defined in `ViewGroup`. The code of `getChildAt` is

```
2914    public View getChildAt(int index) {
2915        try {
2916            return mChildren[index];
2917        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
2918            return null;
2919        }
2920    }
```